# GP Tool Timeout Message in the Console

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a GP tool that creates a PDF report from a map click. I'm testing running multiple reports simultaneously from different browsers. If I run two reports, one will return a PDF to the popup, and the other displays the PDF for a brief instant and then displays "Unable to generate report." If I click on the GP tool again, the report will popup, because I have set the script to check to see if a report has already been generated for that location. In the console log, I see "Timeout Exceeded." This happens after about a minute, even thought the report has obviously been generated. Do I need to set a higher timeout limit?

Here is my code snippet. The clearInterval function is for animated dots while the report is being generated, not related to the timeout.

```
function gpreportResultAvailable(results, messages){
                 domAttr.set(dom.byId("reportLink"),"innerHTML", "Forecast Report");

                 window.map.infoWindow.clearFeatures();

                 var contentResult;

                 results = true;

                 if(results){
                       contentResult ='<a target="_blank" href="' + reportPath + '"><IMG SRC="' + pdfIcon + '"width=25% height=25%/></a>';
                 }
                 else{
                       contentResult = "Unable To Generate Report";
                 }
                 clearInterval(dots);
                 window.map.infoWindow.resize(256,256);
                 window.map.infoWindow.setContent(contentResult);
                 window.map.infoWindow.setTitle(displayCountry + " Forecast Analysis Report");

                };
```